# MAVEN - generating jboss 7 (or EAP 6.x) modules from dependencies

Tags: maven, jboss, jboss7.x

I would like to ask, if there is some maven plugin (or another way) to generate jboss modules hierarchy (with modules.xml files) from maven dependencies (or in list of libraries for such a maven plugin) ?

I have found this plugin :
https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/SJBMMP/smartics+JBoss+Modules+Maven+Plugin;jsessionid=3CA5AE2D1DEB5DFB62C1E64692EDCAB6

But documentation / usage pages seem to be offline (or for some reason I cannot open page).

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755255/generate-an-xml-file-with-all-dependencies-with-maven duplicate of this maybe?

Comment: Thank you - i have read it. It is describing how to generate just xml file - modules.xml. But i would like to have complete directory jboss module structure with libraries - jar files.

Comment: In that case using the plugin is your best bet (the site doesn't seem to be down for me).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried [SMARTICS](https://www.smartics.eu/smartics-jboss-modules-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) plugin plugin and it created for each maven module special JAR file with ALL dependencies in it.

It is like using maven assembly plugin but all libraries are packed in standalone jar which can be placed into own jboss module. Than in your application : **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** you reference to this librari (e.g. jar file) and application has all libraries provided.

But splitting dependencies into own directories and generating modules.xml is not possible (confirmed by JBOSS EAP support).

I will create standalone maven project (something like "JBOSS-modules BOM project") which will generate such structure (this structure will be ready for usage on jboss).

Answer (score 0):

I just would like to add an introduction to the mentioned plugin for Maven:

https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/BLOG/2013/10/18/Maven+Plugin+to+generate+a+Modules+Directory+for+JBoss+AS+7

The article includes screenshots that help new users to get an idea on how the plugin generates separate modules.

(I would like to comment to your answer, but unfortunately I'm some points from being entitles to do so :( )